# Angular 9 Bootstrap 4 Multi-Step Modal

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am in need of a multi-step modal for my Angular app. I'm fairly new to Angular and was hoping this would be a simple task, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find any solutions. Has anyone ever created one before? Not sure if I possess the skills needed to create one. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, it's not really been "a" multi-step modal, but rather a series of modals, with each having buttons that go where I want them to go, in most cases, to another modal. You can encompass them all in the same modal, and just have a bunch of ngIf statements that hide all of the div's that aren't part of the current step, or you could literally have 5 different modals.

I have done the former, where I used ngIf.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <ng-container *ngIf="panelNum == 1"> Put entire panel code here</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="panelNum == 2"> Put entire panel code here</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="panelNum == 3"> Put entire panel code here</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="panelNum == 4"> Put entire panel code here</ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="panelNum == 5"> Put entire panel code here</ng-container>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="next()">Next</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="prev()">Prev</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Then in your TS file:

```
next() { 
 if (this.panelNum < 5) this.panelNum++; else this.panelNum = 1;
}

prev() {
 if (this.panelNum > 1) this.panelNum--; else this.panelNum = 5;
}
```

You could get as complex as you'd like with arrays, components, and other ways to manage the panel, but this is meant to directly answer your question. You can use either Div's or ng-containers, whatever you'd like.

Comment: Never thanked you for the awesome answer, it helped me a lot! I have another question I was wondering if you could help me with?

Comment: Glad I could help. Sure! I would just post the question appropriately, then comment with a link - that way you can consider more than one answer, and others will benefit!